# R isTRUE logic incoherence

Tags: r, if-statement

I am tying to code a new variable based on ifs and elses using `isTRUE` and am having difficulty. I would like to have a condition such as

```
if (isTRUE(t$a > t$b)) {
  t$c <- 0
} else if (isTRUE(t$a < t$b)) {
  t$c <- 1
} else {
  t$c <- 2
}
```

Consider the following data:

```
t<-as.data.frame(c(1:5))
names(t)<-"a"
t$b<-c(5:1)
```

Running the above code gives c values as always being 2 i.e. `isTRUE(t$a > t$b)` and `isTRUE(t$a < t$b)` are always FALSE.

Comment: From documentation *`isTRUE(x) is an abbreviation of identical(TRUE, x), and so is true if and only if x is a length-one logical vector whose only element is TRUE and which has no attributes (not even names).`*, so is `identical(TRUE, t$a < t$b)` or `identical(TRUE, t$a > t$b)` returns `TRUE` to you? Or you think they should for some reason? What's exactly the question?

Comment: OK, so `isTRUE` is redundant. Removing this element from the if statement returns the desired results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the help for `isTRUE`:

```
 ‘isTRUE(x)’ is an abbreviation of ‘identical(TRUE, x)’, and so is
 true if and only if ‘x’ is a length-one logical vector whose only
 element is ‘TRUE’ and which has no attributes (not even names).
```

This is probably not what you want.

I'm guessing that you want a vector, `t$c` that is 0 if `t$a>t$b`, 1 if `t$a<t$b` and 2 otherwise. In R, we can do that in a single vectorised operation:

Easier setup:

```
> t = data.frame(a=1:5, b=5:1)
> t
  a b
1 1 5
2 2 4
3 3 3
4 4 2
5 5 1
```

Now if c is 0 if a>b, 1 if a

```
> t$c=2-((t$a>t$b)+(t$a!=t$b))
> t
  a b c
1 1 5 1
2 2 4 1
3 3 3 2
4 4 2 0
5 5 1 0
```

Logical operations (`>`, `!=` etc) operate along vectors, and evaluate numerically to 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE. If you try typing parts of my expression for `t$c` you should learn how this all works together.

If you don't like that tricksy boolean arithmetic, a couple of nested `ifelse` functions work:

```
t$c = ifelse(t$b>t$a, 1, ifelse(t$b==t$a,2,0))
```

This has the advantage of being a bit more readable - if b>a its 1 otherwise if b=a its 2 otherwise its 0. Note how `ifelse` works, like lots of R functions, on each element of a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `sign()` and indexing a vector of desired values:

```
t <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=5:1);
t;
##   a b
## 1 1 5
## 2 2 4
## 3 3 3
## 4 4 2
## 5 5 1
t$c <- c(1,2,0)[sign(t$a-t$b)+2];
t;
##   a b c
## 1 1 5 1
## 2 2 4 1
## 3 3 3 2
## 4 4 2 0
## 5 5 1 0
```

The advantage here is that you can easily change the desired values later, because they're defined explicitly in the indexed vector as (*`a<b`*,*`a==b`*,*`a>b`*). Spacedman's solution to use logical arithmetic is rather brilliant (+1 from me!), but does not easily lend itself to future changes in values.

Comment: I think nested `ifelse` is probably a better solution on a few levels, so I've edited my brilliance a bit :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought of doing that, but I've never really liked nested `ifelse()` calls. Feels too much like Lisp :)

Comment: One thing I don't like about nested `ifelse` is that you are doing the nested test on things that have already passed the outer test, which seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

use a nested  ifelse

```
t$c=ifelse(t$a<t$b,1,

ifelse(t$a>t$b,0,2)

)
```

from help of nested ifelse

?ifelse

### S4 method for class 'db.obj':

ifelse((test, yes, no))

Arguments
test
A db.obj object, which has only one column. The column can be casted into boolean values.
yes
A normal value or a db.obj object. It is the returned value when test is TRUE.
no
The returned value when test is FALSE.